# How can I trap a return of two variables with an if statement using bash?

Tags: macos, bash

My task is to list a user's folder in /Users on a mac. I have to allow for dupe folders (large enterprise of 650 mac clients) or where a desktop analyst has backed up a folder and appended something. My `$fourFour` variable picks that up. However, I must flag that for logging.

This is where I have got below. The variable `$fourFour` may return one or more folders and I need to get the if statement to echo this accordingly.

```
folders=$(ls -d */ | grep $fourFour | awk '{print $(NF)}' | sed 's/\///')
echo folders is $folders
if [[ "$folders" == "" ]]; then
    echo no items
else
    echo one or more items
fi
```

Comment: It would be better if you can tell us what you are trying to do. YOu can definitely avoid 4 piped commands on 1st line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) unless you absolutely have to. Your code above has *major* issues with whitespace in folder names.
2. [Bash arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) can be your friend:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   shopt -s nullglob

   folders=(*$fourFour*/)

   # Remove the trailing slashes
   folders=("${folders[@]%/}")

   if [[ "${#folders[@]}" -gt 0 ]]; then
       echo "Folders:" "${folders[@]}"
   else
       echo "No folders"
   fi
   ```

Comment: This works for me if I modify the greater than to 1 and echo "only one folder" or otherwise echo "more folders" - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to call so many tools to find your folders. Just use the shell (bash)

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob 
for dir in *$fourFour*/  # putting a slash "/" ensures you get directory entries
do
   echo "Do something with $dir"
   # if you want to check if its empty folder
   v=$(echo "$dir"/*)
   case "${#v}" in
     0) echo "No files in $dir";;
     *) echo "Files in $dir";;
   esac
done
```

if you just want to check whether there are any folders that matched your pattern

```
v=$(echo "$four"/)
case "${#v}" in
     0) echo "0 item";;
     *) echo "1 or more item";;
esac
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants : he wants to echo if there are "no items" or "one or more items".

Comment: it is not clear whether he wants to check if there are folders matching his `grep` pattern, or if he wants to check whether the folders matched contains 0 files (or not).